# Android Emulator process terminated on launching emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I don't seem to understand why my emulator fails to launch even though I have sufficient storage on my system and I have tried deleting the emulators and recreating them again from the start. Also, have updated Android Studio the latest Flamingo version Patch 2. Still doesn't seem to work. I have also checked the log file for the emulator where I was unable to find specific details as to why it fails to launch on my system. I will be providing the error log below when I try to launch the emulator. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
2023-06-27 11:38:08,121 [ 253395] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 4 API 33 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741819
java.lang.Throwable: Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741819
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:184)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorProcessHandler$ConsoleListener.onTextAvailable(EmulatorProcessHandler.kt:89)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor68.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$2.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:248)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy65.onTextAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTextAvailable(ProcessHandler.java:222)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessTerminatedListener.processTerminated(ProcessTerminatedListener.java:54)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor139.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$2.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:248)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy65.processTerminated(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.lambda$notifyTerminated$2(ProcessHandler.java:206)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$TasksRunner.execute(ProcessHandler.java:281)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:189)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyProcessTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:185)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseProcessHandler.onOSProcessTerminated(BaseProcessHandler.java:61)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler$1.lambda$startNotified$0(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:98)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessWaitFor.lambda$new$0(ProcessWaitFor.java:45)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:212)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessWaitFor.lambda$new$1(ProcessWaitFor.java:23)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
2023-06-27 11:38:08,124 [ 253398] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 4 API 33 - Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2  Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639
2023-06-27 11:38:08,124 [ 253398] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 4 API 33 - JDK: 17.0.6; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2023-06-27 11:38:08,125 [ 253399] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 4 API 33 - OS: Windows 10
2023-06-27 11:38:08,544 [ 253818]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_4_API_33 is online, assuming it's not
```